# GaborFilter for pattern extraction

Tags: image-processing, filtering

I am trying to use the GaborFilter to extract features such as pixel clusters forming straight lines in a specific direction from images. How ever the Gabor filter is proving hard for me to understand even though I have been trying hard to read about it. Please use this sample image to extract only vertical lines with a tolerance of about 20 degrees. I have tried it by doing trial and error and I am getting close to favorable results, but I am unable to control the tolerance and feel like I don't realy understand how the filter is working. I would really appreciate it if you could give me brief tips on how to control the filter and the tolerance. 
Here is the picture I used and the out put I got from my code after processing to extract only vertical lines[image]
    ColorReplace[GaborFilter[i3, 6, {0, 1}, 6] // ImageAdjust, Gray]

[image]
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 ColorReplace[GaborFilter[i3, rr, {0, ss}, jj] // ImageAdjust, Gray],
 {rr, 1, 10},
 {jj, 1, 10},
 {ss, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps with trial and error. But I am still not sure how the filter works, so that I can do accurate work.

Comment: One performs a convolution with Gabor filters of different parameters.  Look on wikipedia or any site describing the process.